# Cannot add code to AWS Lambda function using CloudFormation

Tags: aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation

I'm trying to create the Cloud Formation Stack. The Stack was deployed correctly. Lambda function was created, but the code is not getting added as inline to the function.

It says

> Your Lambda function "lambda_function" cannot be edited inline since the file name specified in the handler does not match a file name in your deployment package.

**Cloud Formation Code:**

```
  LambdaFunction:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          import json

          def lambda_handler(event,context):
              #Creating delete request
              ...

      Description: Lambda function.
      FunctionName: lambda_function
      Handler: lambda_function.lambda_handler
      Role : !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Runtime: python2.7
      Timeout: 5
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The first part of the handler should always be `index` if you specify the code inline.

> If you specify your source code as inline text by specifying the ZipFile property within the Code property, specify index.function_name as the handler.
>   http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-lambda-function.html

So just use this:

```
LambdaFunction:
    Type: "AWS::Lambda::Function"
    Properties:
      Code:
        ZipFile: !Sub |
          import json

          def lambda_handler(event,context):
              #Creating delete request
              ...

      Description: Lambda function.
      FunctionName: lambda_function
      Handler: index.lambda_handler
      Role : !GetAtt LambdaExecutionRole.Arn
      Runtime: python2.7
      Timeout: 5
```

Notice `index.lambda_handler` instead of `lambda_function.lambda_handler`.