# CloudFormation script to return binary from API Gateway and Lambda

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, api-gateway

There is a lot of information already on StackOverflow about returning binary content from API Gateway and Lambda but little in the way of detailed guaranteed working solutions. After chasing my tail for a couple of days I would love to stop trying to solve this!

What I am after is a CloudFormation script that creates an API Gateway and a Lambda. A GET call to the resource on API Gateway should return a binary PNG created by the Lambda. The Lambda code should be [inlined](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43634640/cannot-add-code-to-aws-lambda-function-using-cloudformation) in the CloudFormation script so that the solution is self-contained. My suggestion is that the Lambda always return a PNG (a 12x12 pixel downward arrow) whose base 64 encoding is:

```
iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAwAAAAMCAMAAABhq6zVAAAABlBMVEX///8AAABVwtN+AAAAF0lEQVQImWNgoAJghABkHrIcskpSjAUABSYAEabdEBsAAAAASUVORK5CYII=
```

Note that I have a working CloudFormation script for returning a binary via API Gateway and Lambda from S3 using HTTP Redirect but I would prefer to do it directly without the overhead of writing the binary file to S3.

A CloudFormation script would be a terrific contribution for this problem because it's easy to deploy and verify and can easily be modified so that developers can quickly produce a production ready infrastructure-as-code artifact.

To be very greedy about this I'd love to see common problems like this addressed by an active team of AWS devs and published publicly (say at [AWS Samples](https://github.com/aws-samples)).

Thanks in advance!